# Maintain elements placements as screen resolution changes

Tags: html, css

This is my site [www.foxboxretail.com](http://www.foxboxretail.com) . In front banner slider there is problem with css code. Problem is banner navigations placements gets change as screen size gets change f.g.

1360px resolutionv (It's perfect)

[image]

1920px resolution (navigation position of slider changed.)

[image]
In above image you can see navigation gets slightly upper side which mess the design. How do I maintain for all screen size?

css

```
.slide-part{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:400px;
    position:relative
}

.fadein {
    padding-top: 27%;
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1600px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    min-height:60px;
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%; 
    width: auto\9;
    object-fit:fill;
    height:400px
}

.banner-links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.banner-links-inner {
    width:auto;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.banner-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.banner-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 50px 15px 50px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slide-part">
        <!--slider-starts-->
        <div class="fadein">

            <img id="img01" style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" src="images/products/1.jpg" />
            <img id="img02" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="images/products/2.jpg" />
            <img id="img03" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="images/products/3.jpg" />
            <img id="img04" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" src="images/products/4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <!--slide-ends-->
        <div class="banner-links">
            <div class="banner-links-inner">
                <ul class="banner-nav">
                    <li><a class="img1 current" data-id="img01" href="#">Helicopter Tour Mumbai</a></li>
                    <li><a class="img2" data-id="img02" href="#">JBL Flip II Offer</a></li>
                    <li><a class="img3" data-id="img03" href="#">Dominos 20% Off</a></li>
                    <li class="no-border"><a class="img4" data-id="img04" href="#">Paragliding</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want it where?centered? You now have float:right so the whole div floats right....

Comment: @GeorgePant can you tell me where you float:right & to which element?

Comment: @GeorgePant actually my banner image size is 1920px X 468px. So it looks good in that resolution. In my css I have kept object-fit:cover so in 1360 resolution Image gets out of screen. How can I avoid this? This is possible only with media queries?

Comment: I would handle lower resolutions with media queries for sure....

Comment: And personally I would not make the whole slider an image.I would make a div with text etc and a background image since you have text inside it that would be a better aprroach in my opinion.Now that you have it as an image you will probably have problems making your site responsive.You will probably  need another image for the mobile version and change images with media queries....

Comment: Of course removing `min-height` would prevent it getting out of screen in 1360px resolution.But i doubt that would be what you want.Use media queries to handle other resolutions

Comment: @GeorgePant Good idea to keep image content as HTML format & just to  have image in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a max-height to your slider images should do what you want.

```
.fadein img {
 max-height:468px;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry. But I think you got my question wrong. There is no issue of top menu. As you can seen in my second image where slider navigation is there. Can you see that the black transparent menu it goes slightly upper with slider there is I have problem.

Comment: o sorry about that...What browser you are using? in chrome and 1920px i do not see that the slider navigation is ok